# javascript mouseover/out combined with click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new in programming, please give me a mercy. Below is my code:

```
$(function(){
document.getElementById("custom_link").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
document.getElementById("siteContent").contentDocument.getElementById("custom_div").classList.toggle('highlightDiv');
},false)})

$(function(){
    document.getElementById("custom_link").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("siteContent").contentDocument.getElementById("custom_div").classList.add('highlightDiv');
    },false)})
```

What I want to do is:

1. when the user **hovers mouse** on "custom_link", the "custom_div" is being highlighted.
2. when the user **moves mouse out off** "custom_link", the highlight at "custom_div" is eliminated.
3. when the user **clicks** at "custom_link", "custom_div" is being highlight again. However, when the user moves mouse out, the 'highlightDiv' is still being added to "custom_div".

According to my code, it does not work properly because the behavior when hovering is strange. It would be very nice if you can explain me with full code structure or jsfiddle example. Thank you for your advance help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ETrjA/2/

```
$('#custom_link').hover(function () {
    $('#custom_div').toggleClass('highlighted'); 
});

$('#custom_link').click(function (e) {
   $('#custom_div').addClass('highlighted');
   $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

You only need one class `highlighted` and you can access the link element directly within the `click` event callback via `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. I had forgotten to inform that the "custom_div" which I would like to highlight, it is in iFrame page(same domain). Could you please suggest me how to access the div in iFrame?

Comment: Basically, `$('iframe').contents().find('#custom_div');` if it's the same domain.

Comment: could you please clarify how can I implement iframe reference in the code. I tried to embed `$('iframe').contents().find('#custom_div');`  to the code but nothing happened.  Besides, "Custom_link" is in parent document. But "Custom_div" is in iframe document. Thanks again for help.

Comment: If there's only one iframe in your document, `$('iframe')` should reference it correctly. There are other factors for why it could not be working. Your javascript could be running before the document and/or iframe is fully loaded. Also, you should get used to using the built-in Web Inspector, Firebug, etc. and break points for whatever browser you're using. That will help you a ton when trying to debug these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Javascript with its framework jQuery. Stick with jQuery for this.

```
// CSS: Create the highlight accessible with two classnames.

.highlight, .highlight_stay{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
     $('.custom_link').hover(function(){
          $(this).addClass('highlight');
      }, function(){
          $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      });

      $('.custom_link').click(function(){
           $(this).addClass('highlight_stay');
      });
});
```

Comment: There are some errors in your code you should change the hover function from }), function to }, function and the hightlight css to highlight http://jsfiddle.net/95aGH/1/

Answer (score 0):

here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/8GV7B/2/

```
 $(function(){
        mouse_is_clicked = false;
         $(".custom_link").hover(function(){ 
            $("#container").addClass("highlight");
        }, function(){ 
            if(!mouse_is_clicked){ 
                $("#container").removeClass("highlight");
            }else{
                mouse_is_clicked = false;
            }
        });

          $(".custom_link").click(function(){
               $("#container").addClass("highlight");
              mouse_is_clicked = true;
          });
    });
```