# In between parent and iframe: mouseover/out combined with click behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new in programming. Please give me a mercy.
According to the post [mouseover/out combined with click behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828995/javascript-mouseover-out-combined-with-click-behavior) .
I would like to ask further question since I still cannot achieve the task.

Here below is my code:

**Child.html**

```
<div id="custom_div">This div will be highlighted</div>
```

**Parent.html**

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src="Child.html"></iframe>    
<a href="#" id="custom_Link">Click to highlight the custom div in Child.html</a>

<script>
    $('#iframeID').contents().find('#custom_div');

    $('#custom_Link').hover(function () {
        $('#custom_div').toggleClass('highlight'); 
    });

    $('#Custom_Link').click(function (e) {
       $('#Custom_div').addClass('highlight');
       $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });
    </script>
```

What I want to do is:

1. when the user **hovers mouse** on "custom_link", the "custom_div" is being highlighted.
2. when the user **moves mouse out off** "custom_link", the highlight at "custom_div" is eliminated.
3. when the user **clicks** at "custom_link", "custom_div" is being highlight. However, when the user moves mouse out, the 'highlightDiv' is still being added to "custom_div".

Could you please help me to dissolve this? I sought a lot of "accessing iframe element by Jquery" issue ,however, I still cannot understand. It would be very nice if you could provide Jsfiddle example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand your requirement currently this should resolve this issue

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function (){
       var triggered_div = $('#iframeID').contents().find('#custom_div');
           $('#custom_Link').hover(function () {
                 triggered_div.toggleClass('highlight'); 
             });
         $('#Custom_Link').click(function (e) {
             triggered_div.addClass('highlight');
            $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
         });

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W4dUa/ should do what you are asking for, if I understood right, however:

First of all, classes and IDs are case sensitive - revise your code, as you have bits like this: `$('#Custom_Link')` with uppercase *C* that is different from `id="custom_Link"`

I believe that this is because you're unbinding `mouseenter mouseleave` on `click`:

```
   $(e.currentTarget).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

from http://api.jquery.com/hover/

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

for that reason,

```
$('#custom_Link').hover(function () {
    $('#custom_div').toggleClass('highlight'); 
});
```

does not "work" anymore and the `highlight` class stays on your `div`

Comment: I did change the id concerning with case sensitive. Nevertheless, nothing happened. From inspector console, it returned no error, however, no effect taken as well.

Comment: there is no problem when custom_link and custom_div are in the same html document. Obviously, when I put iframe in, it performs nothing. :(